# 503 return from server is branded as CORS violation by Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cors, http-status-code-503

The following has been seen in Chrome's console (anonymized domains, boldface has been added):

```
> somesite.ourdomain.org:44301/api/v1.0/AppCache/AdministrationStatusApi:1 GET https://devesaapi.abim.org:44301/api/v1.0/AppCache/AdministrationStatusApi 503 (Service Unavailable)
> esa:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://somesite.ourdomain.org:44301/api/v1.0/AppCache/AdministrationStatusApi' from origin 'https://othersite.ourdomain.org:44301' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

The true reason for the 503 is that one of the load-balanced nodes was not responding correctly to the load balancer. However, Chrome decided that since the 503 response didn't have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on this cross-site request, it should complain about CORS.

The reason this is bad is because it misled our developers and wasted some time hunting down a CORS problem that wasn't really there.

Is Chrome really doing the right thing by reporting that this request, which returned 503, is a CORS violation??  What do other browsers do?

Google Chrome stable Version 72.0.3626.109 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10

**EDIT**: At least [one other developer blogger](https://davidtruxall.com/misleading-cors-errors/) agrees with me.

Comment: Just my opinion, but it should be worded as more of a suggestion/possiblity, which it is.

Comment: even if response had `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header somehow CORS would fail anyway. it's required for response to have 2xx status code. proof: https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0 So it's just header been checked at first place.

Comment: My reading of your link is "if the response was not success, don't continue". My complaint is that Chrome is saying "if the response was not success, **say it's a CORS problem**." That was definitely misleading in our case, and I think in the general case too.

Comment: Mystery downvoter, if my question is bad, could I get a comment explaining why?