# All Server Errors Appear as 500 CORS Error, Fast-API in Docker Image

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I am running a fast-api server in a docker container (using uvicorn).
Every error from the server appears as a 500

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

even when I know the code is actually throwing a 401 or something else. The expected error message is not shown however.

When running locally in python errors show up as expected.
Other requests are going through w/out the CORS error and this is only coming up in situations I expect the server to throw an error.

The app has the following CORS middleware

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Comment: If it appers as a 500 error (you can inspect the request in your browser's debug network tools - I assume that's where you see the 500 error) - then it's a 500 internal server error - and not a 401 error that's being returned. Look at the server logs for your docker container and you should see what exceptions are being thrown that you're not handling.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this from Chrome, this is a sort of known problem, that it will display server/network errors as CORS errors. See e.g. [this article](https://davidtruxall.com/misleading-cors-errors/) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54795541/503-return-from-server-is-branded-as-cors-violation-by-chrome).